# Probability of three independent events.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let the three independent events $ A, B,$ and $ C$  be such that $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)= \frac14.$  find $P[(A^*\cap B^*) \cup C].$

My solution starts from using the probability of their complements which is $\frac34$, I do not know how to answer this question. Please help.

Comment: Hi Jonarie - It's considered polite on this site to share what you've thought about and tried, and to formulate your question as a *question* rather than seeming like a textbook exercise.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for the reminder

Comment: Also asked at http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/117821/10259

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help your understanding to break down the problem based upon a few simple rules:

\begin{align}
P[(A^*\cap B^*) \cup C] &= P(A^* \cap B^*) + P(C) - P[(A^*\cap B^*) \cap C] \\
                        &= P(A^*)P(B^*) + P(C) - P(A^* \cap B^*)P(C) \\
                        &= P(A^*)P(B^*) + P(C) - P(A^*)P(B^*)P(C) \\
                        &= P(A^*)P(B^*)(1-P(C)) + P(C) \\
                        &= P(A^*)P(B^*)P(C^*) + P(C)
\end{align}

The general idea here being that, if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then:

1. $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$
2. $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A)P(B)$

And of course $P(A^*) = 1-P(A)$.